# tensorflow giving nans when calculating gradient with sparse tensors

Tags: tensorflow

The following snippet is from a fairly large piece of code but hopefully I can give all the information necessary:

y2 = tf.matmul(y1,ymask)

dist = tf.norm(ystar-y2,axis=0)

y1 and y2 are 128x30 and ymask is 30x30. ystar is 128x30. dist is 1x30. When ymask is the identity matrix, everything works fine. But when I set it to be all zeros, apart from a single 1 along the diagonal (so as to set all columns but one in y2 to be zero), I get nans for the gradient of dist with respect to y2, using tf.gradients(dist, [y2]). The specific value of dist is [0,0,7.9,0,...], with all the ystar-y2 values being around the range (-1,1) in the third column and zero elsewhere.

I'm pretty confused as to why a numerical issue would occur here, given there are no logs or divisions, is this underflow? Am I missing something in the maths?

For context, I'm doing this to try to train individual dimensions of y, one at a time, using the whole network.

longer version to reproduce:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

batchSize = 128
eta = 0.8
tasks = 30
imageSize = 32**2
groups = 3
tasksPerGroup = 10
trainDatapoints = 10000

w = np.zeros([imageSize, groups * tasksPerGroup])
toyIndex = 0
for toyLoop in range(groups):
    m = np.ones([imageSize]) * np.random.randn(imageSize)
    for taskLoop in range(tasksPerGroup):
        w[:, toyIndex] = m * 0.1 * np.random.randn(1)
        toyIndex += 1

xRand = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, (trainDatapoints, imageSize))
taskLabels = np.matmul(xRand, w) + np.random.normal(0,0.5,(trainDatapoints, groups * tasksPerGroup))
DF = np.concatenate((xRand, taskLabels), axis=1)
trainDF = pd.DataFrame(DF[:trainDatapoints, ])

# define graph variables
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, imageSize])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([imageSize, tasks]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([tasks]))
ystar = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, tasks])
ymask = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [tasks, tasks])
dataLength = tf.cast(tf.shape(ystar)[0],dtype=tf.float32)

y1 = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
y2 = tf.matmul(y1,ymask)
dist = tf.norm(ystar-y2,axis=0)
mse = tf.reciprocal(dataLength) * tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(dist))
grads = tf.gradients(dist, [y2])

trainStep = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(eta).minimize(mse)

# build graph
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

randTask = np.random.randint(0, 9)
ymaskIn = np.zeros([tasks, tasks])
ymaskIn[randTask, randTask] = 1
batch = trainDF.sample(batchSize)
batch_xs = batch.iloc[:, :imageSize]
batch_ys = np.zeros([batchSize, tasks])
batch_ys[:, randTask] = batch.iloc[:, imageSize + randTask]

gradOut = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, ystar: batch_ys, ymask: ymaskIn})

sess.run(trainStep, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, ystar: batch_ys, ymask:ymaskIn})
```

Comment: Please include a self-contained snippet which reproduces the issue (i.e. use constants for `y1`, `y2`, and `ystar`).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, so it took a bit more than just constants to reproduce, have added some code to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very simple reproduction:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  y = tf.zeros(shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32)
  dist = tf.norm(y,axis=0)
  (grad,) = tf.gradients(dist, [y])
  with tf.Session():
    print(grad.eval())
```

Prints:

```
[ nan]
```

The issue is that `tf.norm` computes `sum(x**2)**0.5`. The gradient is `x / sum(x**2) ** 0.5` (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/84333), so when `sum(x**2)` is zero we're dividing by zero.

There's not much to be done in terms of a special case: the gradient as `x` approaches all zeros depends on which direction it's approaching from. For example if `x` is a single-element vector, the limit as `x` approaches 0 could either be 1 or -1 depending on which side of zero it's approaching from.

So in terms of solutions, you could just add a small `epsilon`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def safe_norm(x, epsilon=1e-12, axis=None):
  return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(x ** 2, axis=axis) + epsilon)

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  y = tf.constant([0.])
  dist = safe_norm(y,axis=0)
  (grad,) = tf.gradients(dist, [y])
  with tf.Session():
    print(grad.eval())
```

Prints:

```
[ 0.]
```

Note that this is not actually the Euclidean norm. It's a good approximation as long as the input is much larger than `epsilon`.

Comment: ah, cool cheers, yeah I was forgetting that squaring it in the next step doesn't cancel the root for backprop purposes. using mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(ystar,y2), fixes it too, and i can just keep my dist calc for an output metric, but out of the chain, cheers