# python tensorflow l2 loss over axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, linear-algebra

I am using python 3 with tensorflow 
I have a matrix, each row is a vector, I want to get a distance matrix - that is computer using the [l2 norm loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_loss), each value in the matrix will be a distance between two vectors

e.g

```
Dij = l2_distance(M(i,:), Mj(j,:))
```

Thanks

edit: 
this is not a duplicate [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388794/python-tensorflow-l2-loss-over-axis) that other question is about computing the norm for the each row of a matrix, I need the pairwise norm distance between each row to every other row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute pairwise distance in a batch without replicating tensor in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009647/compute-pairwise-distance-in-a-batch-without-replicating-tensor-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37040451/5085211) shows how to compute the pair-wise sum of squared differences between a collection of vectors. By simply post-composing with the square root, you arrive at your desired pair-wise distances:

```
M = tf.constant([[0, 0], [2, 2], [5, 5]], dtype=tf.float64)
r = tf.reduce_sum(M*M, 1)
r = tf.reshape(r, [-1, 1])
D2 = r - 2*tf.matmul(M, tf.transpose(M)) + tf.transpose(r)
D = tf.sqrt(D2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(D))

# [[0.         2.82842712 7.07106781]
#  [2.82842712 0.         4.24264069]
#  [7.07106781 4.24264069 0.        ]]
```

Comment: could you explain the mathematical logic here? is it according the the (a-b)^2 formula?

Comment: Yep, that, and a bit of broadcasting. The linked answer explains what's going on.

Comment: thanks, could you please add some more information as for why it works mathematically?

Comment: Hm, is there anything in the linked answer that's not already clear? I would end up writing exactly what's in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a TensorFlow operation based on the formula of Euclidean distance (L2 loss).

[image]

```
distance = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(x1, x2))))
```

Sample would be

```
import tensorflow as tf

x1 = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
x2 = tf.constant([4, 5, 6], dtype=tf.float32)

distance = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(x1, x2))))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(distance))
```

As pointed out by @fuglede, if you want to output the pairwise distances, then we can use

```
tf.sqrt(tf.square(tf.subtract(x1, x2)))
```

Comment: That only gives you a single number; if that's what they wanted, they'd probably just use `tf.norm` directly. Rather, I imagine they want to know how to perform the broadcasting you'd do in NumPy to get all pairwise distances at once.

Comment: If that's the case, then we can simply remove the `tf.reduce_mean` to output the pairwise distances.

Comment: If you remove `tf.reduce_mean`, what you get is just the element-wise differences between the two vectors. Their input is an matrix, and they want the pair-wise distances between the rows in that, so that e.g. the diagonal in the result vanishes, i.e. what amounts to `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`.

Comment: what will that output? a matrix that is the pairwise distance between each row to each other row (as vectors)?

Comment: could you please provide an example that will work with a matrix? as stated in the op I have a matrix, each row is a vector, I need the pairwise distance between each vector to every other vector. e.g a 32*100 matrix will provide us with a 32*32 matrix. Thanks.

Comment: @thebeancounter: See the accepted answer in the existing question: If you take that verbatim and apply square-roots element-wise, you'll get your pair-wise distances.

Comment: @fuglede - sorry, can't see that, could you post a complete answer so i'll accept it?